# Upload file in PHP is not required - PHP FORM not working

Tags: php

I am trying to create a form with the posibility to upload a file but it seems that I cannot make this input a none required one. In each time I try to verify that there is no uploaded file the code keeps on getting inside the condition.

```
 if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) && !empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])){
    // Set files location
    $target_dir = "media/";
    $total = count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    // Check if there is files to be uploaded.
      if($total != 0) {
           //$uploadOk = 1;
           for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {

           $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);
           $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
           $namee =$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i];
           // Check if file already exists
           if (file_exists($target_file)) {
               header('location: new_report.php?upload=fileexist');
               $uploadOk = 0;
           }
           // Check file size
           if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"][$i] > 500000) {
               header('location: new_report.php?upload=toobig');
           }
           // Allow certain file formats
           if($imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpg"  ) {
               var_dump($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
              // exit;
             header('location: new_report.php?upload=filenotallowed');
               $uploadOk = 0;
           }
           // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
           if ($uploadOk == 0) {
               echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
           // if everything is ok, try to upload file
           } else {
               if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
               Do something..
               } else {
                   header('location: new_report.php?upload=error');
               }
           }
           }

      }
    }
```

Even if I don't upload a file, I keeps on going inside the do something part of the code.

The html code is :

```
<form action="submit_report.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="fileToUpload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="fileToUpload">
</form>
```

Is meant to be for a multiple choice file

Comment: What does `fileToUpload` have in it? `var_dump($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])`

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: Take a looking into the PHP manual how to [handle file upload forms](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) to see which mistake you made.. It's hard to tell because you didn't provide the minimal code.. A educated guess seeing `fileToUpload[]` in the html i assume you want to upload multiple files at once that means you need to loop the `$_FILES` array in the PHP code.

Comment: This is what I get from var_dump file

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => string '' (length=0)

Comment: like i said already "It's hard to tell because you didn't provide the minimal code" meaning you should provide the minimal code.. And do you have PHP in debugging mode the uploaded files also might be simply to large..

Comment: Use isset method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493605/upload-file-in-php-is-not-required-php-form-not-working/54493648#54493648

Comment: I edit the file and provided the whole code @RaymondNijland

Comment: @Googlian it didn't work .

Comment: Seperate the logic, 1. check for a submission, 2. in that check look for files, if not present just continue, if present enter another conditional. Iterate over your array and make sure they aren't empty.

Comment: @Mohdows did you try my edited version

Comment: @Googlian I got basically the same issue.

Comment: if i was you i would this test this code `<?php

$target_file = 'test.php\0.png';

$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

var_dump($imageFileType);

?>` to check if `pathinfo()` isn't vulnerable in your PHP version against NULL bytes attacks and correctly displayes `.png` and not `.php` and possibly allow a PHP file to be uploaded on the server.. The modern PHP versions stops NULL byte attacks much better so most likely it's won't be a issue there but better to be safe then sorry.

Comment: The error that is always thrown is in the file extension verification, it appears that when the code is running and won't find the specified type of file it gives an error @Googlian

Comment: @Mohdows the latest code is tested and working fine

Comment: @Googlian it doesn't work for me, try to not upload a file and submit the code and tell me what do you see.

Comment: @Mohdows now tried with` if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][0] == "") {}` refer the code

Comment: @Mohdows get the latest code it will work.

Comment: @Mohdows have you tried with the latest

Comment: Yes @Googlian it works, great.

Comment: @Mohdows you can right my question and up votes are appreciated thank you. By make my question right you can close this question.

Comment: @Mohdows by clicking the pass button near by my answer you can set the answer as right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a file `isset` condition and try.

**This code is tested**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']))
    {
        if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][0] == "") {
            die("No files to upload");
        }

        foreach($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
        {
            $file_name = $key . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$key];
            $file_size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'][$key];
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, getcwd() . "/" . time() . $file_name);
        }

        echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='POST'>";
        echo "File:<input name='fileToUpload[]' multiple='multiple' type='file'/><input type='submit' value='Upload'/>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
?>
```

Make sure your HTML form should contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I don't think this will handle the file uploads correctly. This is assuming the `getting inside the condition` means the enter the `else` on every run, right?

Comment: The code is tested @user3783243 so this can work since the user did not provide HTML code

Comment: @Googlian If they upload a file though `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` won't be empty. `if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])` is a good start but I think there needs another check inside and to bypass the file processing when a file isn't uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since the input name is `fileToUpload[]` an array will be always posted, you will need to check for `if count($_FILES['fileToUpload']) { ...` instead of using `isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])`.